# AS3 newbie "match 3" issue - matching types

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I'm trying to make a "match 3" game. Instead of just having one type of each jewel that matches, I want to have 2 different types of each jewel that will then match. I've set up my movieclip with 12 frames, comprised of 6 pairs of different jewels, and randomizing which frame will play. I'm using Gary Rosenzweig's code (Actionscript Game Programming University) as a base.

I have 6 different arrays to hold the matching combinations (eg, m1 = [1,2], m2 = [3,4] ... m6 = [11,12]). I've set up my match conditions like this:

Standard match where frame numbers match directly:

```
 if (mc1.currentFrame == mc2.currentFrame) {
      match.push(mc2);
```

Match where frame numbers are different, but they're part of the same pair and should match:

```
 } else if (mc1.currentFrame in m1 && mc2.currentFrame in m1) {
      match.push(mc2);
```

The problem is that I'm not getting any matches from the 2nd condition. I've set traces up for each condition that show the two frame numbers being compared, but pairs that should be matching aren't.

Help!!!! As a complete AS3 newbie, I've tried to figure this out every which way I can, but no luck so far. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Uh, I've never used "in", so there might be some weirdness with that.

Instead of

```
} else if (mc1.currentFrame in m1 && mc2.currentFrame in m1) {
```

You might try

```
} else if (m1.indexOf(mc1.currentFrame)>-1 &&  m1.indexOf(mc2.currentFrame)>-1) {
```

Oh, you are also checking mc2 current frame against m1 and not m2. Did you want to do that?